# Multiselect option group bootstrap not loading when dynamically generated using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to dynamically generate the below select otp group with boot-strap class code when a button is clicked.
I've used both document.ready() and .on('click') functions while clicking a button. But when I append my resulting generated select opt group to my html document, it doesn't get appended.

This problem only occurs when I dynamically generate the code while the below select otp group works if it's already hard-coded in my html page. Also the select otp works dynamically if the bootstrap class is removed. I hope there's something wrong with the lodaing of my scripts or the bootstrap version.

```
<select id="my_select" class="selectpicker" multiple >
<option>option here </option>
</optgroup></select>
```

Below are the scripts and CSS sheets that I've linked to my html document.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you share example with repro-issue?

Comment: @demo sry! I don't know what do you mean by repro-issue. I'm not good in english :(

Comment: example where we can reproduce your issue/problem

Comment: sure I'll do @demo

Comment: @demo Here's the jfiddle link for my code: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lapmwy7/4/#&togetherjs=M57QAwMi8m

Comment: on click select is added... just it has `display: none!important` by default. https://jsfiddle.net/aqy73ntL/ Working example

Comment: @demo But it only shows the default version of select otpgroup for me ,not the styled boot strap version

Comment: then you can re-initialize selects like https://jsfiddle.net/6m0xj8tL/

Comment: @demo How did you made that work?

Comment: @demo can you explain the block! important and also why refresh is needed. Thank you for you kind help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232915/discussion-between-crox-and-demo).